# How to change routes for Tomcat ROOT, manager, host-manager directories (menus)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have changed ROOT app of Tomcat to /panel directory, because I user "/" directory for my deployed app.
How can I configure Tomcat to access home menu (ROOT app) and managers (manager, host-manager) in other routes, because currently I get error, when trying to navigate /manager

I am accesing home panel on http://localhost:8080/panel/

```
<Context path="/panel" docBase="ROOT"></Context>
```

Clicking "Manage app" routes me to http://localhost:8080/manager/html and gives error

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message Not found
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exist

I tried to add

```
<Context path="/manager" docBase="manager"></Context>
```

But that gives me error

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Error instantiating servlet class
>   [org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet]
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   [org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet]
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Access to class [class
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet] is forbidden. It is a
>   restricted class (implements ContainerServlet interface). A web
>   application must be configured as privileged to be able to load it
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs

.

Comment: When starting with a new tomcat from scratch, simply rename the folder `webApps/ROOT` to 'webApps/panel'. There is no need to override the context configuration in server.xml using `<Context/>` element. What else have I done to the tomcat installation? Can't reproduce due to lack of details.

Comment: Please also take a closer look at the `webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml` to see how manager context is properly configured. This helps you prevent the `java.lang.SecurityException`

Comment: Renaming ROOT folder to panel worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

One option;
In your `server.xml`:

```
<Context path="/manager" privileged="true"/>
```